# What's the total Cosmic Microwave Background energy?

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background, observable-universe

This is a part of my wider attempts at accounting matter in the observable universe.

The total light ever emitted by stars and other space objects is capped around 1% of baryonic mass (in energy equivalent).

[How much light is there in space and how heavy is it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27799/how-much-light-is-there-in-space-and-how-heavy-is-it/27800#27800)

How does the CMB compare to that? How would we calculate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The energy density of the Cosmic Microwave Background (CMB) is $4.19 \times 10^{-14} J/m^3$.

This value can be calculated from the CMB temperature being 2.728 K and

$energy$ $density = aT^4$

where $a$ is the [Radiation Constant](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/RadiationConstant.html).

You can multiply the energy density by your volume of interest such as that of the observable universe if you want total energy.

Comment: For comparison the average density of matter/energy in the universe is around $10^{-9}$ J/m$^3$.